# App crashes everytime : Fatal Exception Main

Tags: java, android

I am making an android weather app that fetches the data from a third party API and present 5 days of weather data to the user. Whenever I try to run my app it crashes. Any help would be appreciated.

**Main Activity-**

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
  private TextView latituteField;
  private TextView longitudeField;
  private LocationManager locationManager;
  private TextView mylocation;
  private TextView Entry1, Entry2, Entry3, Entry4, Entry5;
  private JSONObject jobject1, jobject2, jarray, tempjobject;
  private JSONArray temparray;
  private String provider, string, city;
  private String[] maximum = new String[5];
  private String[] minimum = new String[5];
  private String[] conditions = new String[5];
  private String[] pictureLink = new String[5];
  private Bitmap[] imageCases = new Bitmap[5];
  private ImageView iv1, iv2, iv3, iv4, iv5;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    latituteField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
    longitudeField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView04);
    mylocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView06);
    iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
    iv2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv2);
    iv3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv3);
    iv4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv4);
    iv5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv5);  
    Entry1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.day1);
    Entry2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.day2);
    Entry3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.day3);
    Entry4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.day4);
    Entry5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.day5);


    // Get the location manager
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    // Define the criteria how to select the locatioin provider -> use
    // default
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    // Initialize the location fields
    if (location != null) {
      System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
      onLocationChanged(location);
    } else {
      latituteField.setText("Location not available");
      longitudeField.setText("Location not available");
    } 
        String result;
        try {
            result = new WeatherHttpClient().execute("http://api.wunderground.com/api/796da11422ba3dc2/forecast10day/q/"+city+".json").get();

            try {
                jobject1 = new JSONObject(result);
            jarray = jobject1.getJSONObject("forecast");
            jobject2 = jarray.getJSONObject("simpleforecast");
            temparray = jobject2.getJSONArray("forecastday");
            string = result;

            for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
                 tempjobject= temparray.getJSONObject(i);
                maximum[i] =tempjobject.getString("high");
                minimum[i] = tempjobject.getString("low");
                conditions[i] = tempjobject.getString("conditions");
            }           
            JSONObject j1 = new JSONObject(maximum[0]);
            JSONObject j2 = new JSONObject(minimum[0]);
            JSONObject j3 = new JSONObject(maximum[1]);
            JSONObject j4 = new JSONObject(minimum[1]);
            JSONObject j5 = new JSONObject(maximum[2]);
            JSONObject j6 = new JSONObject(minimum[2]);
            JSONObject j7 = new JSONObject(maximum[3]);
            JSONObject j8 = new JSONObject(minimum[3]);
            JSONObject j9 = new JSONObject(maximum[4]);
            JSONObject j10 = new JSONObject(minimum[4]);

            Entry1.setText("Maximum" + j1.getString("fahrenheit")+"°F"  + "Minimum" + j2.getString("fahrenheit")+"°F "+ conditions[0]);
            Entry2.setText("Maximum" + j3.getString("fahrenheit")+"°F"  + "Minimum" + j4.getString("fahrenheit")+"°F "+ conditions[1]);
            Entry3.setText("Maximum" + j5.getString("fahrenheit")+"°F"  + "Minimum" + j6.getString("fahrenheit")+"°F "+ conditions[2]);
            Entry4.setText("Maximum" + j7.getString("fahrenheit")+"°F"  + "Minimum" + j8.getString("fahrenheit")+"°F "+ conditions[3]);
            Entry5.setText("Maximum" + j9.getString("fahrenheit")+"°F"  + "Minimum" + j10.getString("fahrenheit")+"°F "+ conditions[4]);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                imageCases[i] = new Image().execute(pictureLink[i]).get();
            }
            iv1.setImageBitmap(imageCases[0]);      
            iv2.setImageBitmap(imageCases[1]);
            iv3.setImageBitmap(imageCases[2]);
            iv4.setImageBitmap(imageCases[3]);
            iv5.setImageBitmap(imageCases[5]);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
  }

  /* Remove the locationlistener updates when Activity is paused */
  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude());
    int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude());
    latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
    longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
    Geocoder geoCoder1 = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        String add = "";
        List<Address> addresses;
        List<Address> fromLocation;

            fromLocation = (List<Address>) geoCoder1.getFromLocation(lat,lng, 1);

        addresses = fromLocation;
        if (addresses.size() > 0) 
        {
            for (int i=0; i<((android.location.Address) addresses.get(0)).getMaxAddressLineIndex();i++)
                add += ((android.location.Address) addresses.get(0)).getAddressLine(i) + "\n";
        }
        mylocation.setText(String.valueOf(add));  
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            city = extras.getString("ZipCode");
        }
        else{

            city = ((android.location.Address) addresses.get(0)).getPostalCode();
        }
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), city, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

  } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }}


  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.action_settings:
            Intent aboutIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Options.class);
            startActivity(aboutIntent);
            return true;
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            return true;
        default: 
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);           
        }
    }


  @Override
  public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

  @Override
  public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

  }
  @Override
  public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled provider " + provider,
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
```

**XML-**

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <ScrollView
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:text="@string/Lati"
            android:textSize="20sp" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView03"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:text="@string/Longi"
            android:textSize="20sp" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView04"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:textSize="20sp" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView05"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:text="@string/Locati"
            android:textSize="20sp" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView06"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:paddingTop="15dip"
                android:text="@string/d1"
                android:textSize="20sp" >
            </TextView>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv1"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:contentDescription="Image for climate"
                android:maxHeight="100dp"
                android:maxWidth="100dp" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/day1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="xxxxxxx"
                android:textSize="20sp" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:paddingTop="15dip"
                android:text="@string/d2"
                android:textSize="20sp" >
            </TextView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv2"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:contentDescription="Image for climate"
                android:maxHeight="100dp"
                android:maxWidth="100dp" />

             <TextView
                android:id="@+id/day2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="yyyyyyyyy"
                android:textSize="20sp" >
             </TextView>

             <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:paddingTop="15dip"
                android:text="@string/d3"
                android:textSize="20sp" >
            </TextView>

             <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv3"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:contentDescription="Image for climate"
                android:maxHeight="100dp"
                android:maxWidth="100dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/day3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="yyyyyyyyy"
                android:textSize="20sp" >
        </TextView>

             <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:paddingTop="15dip"
                android:text="@string/d4"
                android:textSize="20sp" >

            </TextView>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv4"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:contentDescription="Image for climate"
                android:maxHeight="100dp"
                android:maxWidth="100dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/day4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="yyyyyyyyy"
                android:textSize="20sp" >
            </TextView>

             <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:paddingTop="15dip"
                android:text="@string/d5"
                android:textSize="20sp" >
            </TextView>

             <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv5"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:contentDescription="Image for climate"
                android:maxHeight="100dp"
                android:maxWidth="100dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/day5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="yyyyyyyyy"
                android:textSize="20sp" >
        </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>       
      </ScrollView>
```

**LogCat Output**

```
10-17 22:26:33.834: D/ActivityThread(29954): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
10-17 22:26:33.834: D/ActivityThread(29954): setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
10-17 22:26:33.834: D/ActivityThread(29954): setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
10-17 22:26:34.014: I/System.out(29954): Provider network has been selected.
10-17 22:26:34.705: W/dalvikvm(29954): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41e90438)
10-17 22:26:34.705: E/AndroidRuntime(29954): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-17 22:26:34.705: E/AndroidRuntime(29954): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.checkweather/com.example.checkweather.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-17 22:26:34.705: E/AndroidRuntime(29954):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
10-17 22:26:34.705: E/AndroidRuntime(29954):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
10-17 22:26:34.705: E/AndroidRuntime(29954):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
10-17 22:26:34.705: E/AndroidRuntime(29954):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
10-17 22:26:34.705: E/AndroidRuntime(29954):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-17 22:26:34.705: E/AndroidRuntime(29954):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-17 22:26:34.705: E/AndroidRuntime(29954):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
10-17 22:26:34.705: E/AndroidRuntime(29954):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-17 22:26:34.705: E/AndroidRuntime(29954):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-17 22:26:34.705: E/AndroidRuntime(29954):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
10-17 22:26:34.705: E/AndroidRuntime(29954):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
10-17 22:26:34.705: E/AndroidRuntime(29954):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-17 22:26:34.705: E/AndroidRuntime(29954): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-17 22:26:34.705: E/AndroidRuntime(29954):    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
10-17 22:26:34.705: E/AndroidRuntime(29954):    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
10-17 22:26:34.705: E/AndroidRuntime(29954):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:154)
10-17 22:26:34.705: E/AndroidRuntime(29954):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
10-17 22:26:34.705: E/AndroidRuntime(29954):    at com.example.checkweather.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:103)
10-17 22:26:34.705: E/AndroidRuntime(29954):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5179)
10-17 22:26:34.705: E/AndroidRuntime(29954):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
10-17 22:26:34.705: E/AndroidRuntime(29954):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
10-17 22:26:34.705: E/AndroidRuntime(29954):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: I would look at using GSON to deserialise your json, create some models and look at threading via services or asynctasks to improve this a lot.

Comment: Graham: I am very new to programming. Hence I know very basics.

Answer (score 1):

You only create values for `maximum[0]` and `maximum[1]`, same for minimum.

So when you call

```
JSONObject j4 = new JSONObject(minimum[2]);
```

you pass `null` to the `JSONObject`.

Comment: @HimanshuAdhwaryu but should have a diferente stacktrace. can you update your question with the new code and stacktrace?

Comment: And, when you comment use the `@` sintax to alert the user like i did in my previous comment.

Comment: ahh not I got my mistake. I didn't fetch the imageurl from JSON first and was simply doing imageview. App looks fine now. Thanks